# Excel VBA for single message box for all empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return the address of all cells that are empty in the range `D8:D13`.
I would like to display a single message box listing all the returned addresses if there are any.

For example:
[image]

I would like a message box saying something like *"D9,D10,D11 and D13 are empty."*

Comment: I've updated the wording of the question.  If this has changed the meaning of the question (I don't think it has) please feel free to roll-back.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetEmptCells()

Dim C As Range
Dim MsgStr As String

For Each C In Range("D8:D13") ' <-- change the range in this line
    If C.Value2 = "" Then
        If MsgStr = "" Then
            MsgStr = C.Address(False, False)
        Else
            MsgStr = MsgStr & "," & C.Address(False, False)
        End If
    End If
Next C

MsgBox MsgStr & " cells are empty"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, This code is working, It is showing with cells are empty, but the output am expecting in message box is the cells which are corresponding to empty. Eg: B,C,D is having empty. can you help to get this.

Comment: That might be my fault after changing the wording of the question - saying that though, how does the range `D8:D13` equate to `B,C & D`?

Comment: @Sasi what is B, C, D ?

Comment: A quick update which will change the wording of the message.  After the `For...Next` loop add this code: `Dim lLastComma As Long: lLastComma = InStrRev(MsgStr, ",")` (find last comma in message).  `If lLastComma > 0 Then: MsgStr = Left(MsgStr, lLastComma - 1) & Replace(MsgStr, ",", " and ", lLastComma, 1)` - replace last comma with ' and '. `MsgBox MsgStr & " cell" & IIf(lLastComma > 0, "s are ", " is ") & "empty"` - will display `cell is empty` or `cells are empty`.

Comment: @Shai: say, name, age, date of birth, if name and date of birth is empty, i need to get message with name and dob is empty. or if age and name is empty, message with name and age is empty. instead name,age i had Alphabets.